# Combining CSS Selector * with last-of-type

Tags: css-selectors

I want to use both [href*="foo"] and :last-of-type. I can't find a combination that works. The output is like:

Artist Name
Genre
Genre
Topic
Topic
Topic

```
.tags a[href*="genre"]:last-of-type { margin-bottom: 1rem; }
```

I want to style some bottom margin on the last "artist" and the last "genre". Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/40whp0ph/. Note that the margin-bottom for Artist and the last Genre are what I want, but not the margin-bottom for the first Genre.

Can anybody point me to how to remove the margin-bottom from all but the last Genre?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't use :last-of-type like that. You will need to modify your HTML to suit your use case. Like putting each type of element in its own container and then styling the last child of each container.

Comment: Or you can leave the HTML unchanged and use the `+` combinator...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is the totally underappreciated `+` combinator.
With this, we can give some selector a style, and then reset the style for the same selector if it occurs again directly after. In other words, give the style only to the first element with this class.

```css
.tags a { display: block; }
.tags a[href*="genre"] { margin-top: 1rem; }
.tags a[href*="genre"] + a[href*="genre"] { margin-top: 0; }
.tags a[href*="topic"] { margin-top: 1rem; }
.tags a[href*="topic"] + a[href*="topic"] { margin-top: 0; }
```

```html
<div class="tags">
  <h3>Tags</h3>
  <a href="https://awesomechristianmusic.com/tag/artist-glad/" rel="tag">Artist: Glad</a>
  <a href="https://awesomechristianmusic.com/tag/genre-a-capella/" rel="tag">Genre: A Capella</a>
  <a href="https://awesomechristianmusic.com/tag/genre-hymns/" rel="tag">Genre: Hymns</a>
  <a href="https://awesomechristianmusic.com/tag/topic-faith/" rel="tag">Topic: Faith</a>
  <a href="https://awesomechristianmusic.com/tag/topic-god/" rel="tag">Topic: God</a>
  <a href="https://awesomechristianmusic.com/tag/topic-prayer/" rel="tag">Topic: Prayer</a>
</div>
```

Or, if you are sure there won't be anything else in the div except the  elements, you can shorten the css to something like this:

```css
.tags a {display: block;}
.tags a:not([href*="genre"]) + a[href*="genre"],
.tags a:not([href*="topic"]) + a[href*="topic"] {margin-top: 1rem;}
```

Comment: Aha! That's a most excellent answer. It never occurred to me to use :not with +...kind of like the owl selector in reverse. I will keep both in mind for future projects.